# Как верно указать путь к app.properties для запуска jar из консоли

Tags: java, jar, properties

У меня файл с настройками app.properties

лежит по пути
main/resources/app.properties

когда я собираю jar приложения и запускаю его в консоли java -jar

выдается сообщение src/main/resources/app.properties не обнаружено

как это можно исправить?

Comment: Работать в коде с app.properties как с ресурсом, а не с файлом.

Comment: try (InputStream is = MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("app.properties")) вот так у меня. это не верно?

Comment: Это верно. Странно, что проблема возникает. Откройте jar-файл любым архиватором и убедитесь, что файл app.properties в нём есть.

Comment: да я не верно jar собрал(

Comment: Если вопрос решён - так закрой его.

Answer (score 0):

нужно было верно настроить корневой класс в мавене

Answer (score -1):

`java -jar -Dspring.config.location=<path> -jar <jar>`

Запуск файла application.properties с кастомным расположением в Spring.